# Converting other time zones into local time zone (offset)

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz, localtime

I'm trying to make a function that would take two arguments as input.

1. The time as a string ("2021-08-13 19:00")
2. The time zone (-4)

I want the function to convert the time with the given time zone to my computer's local time zone (offset). Could anyone help out?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way in Python to get your local time zone.  You can get your current local time offset, but that's not the same thing.  And judging by your question you may be confused by the difference too.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yeah I meant the offset, sorry!

Comment: The offset is only good for the current moment though, it might be different yesterday or tomorrow and your time will be off.

Comment: @Mark: "good for the current moment" is probably "good enough".

Comment: @martineau if "current moment" is good enough, why is one of the parameters to the function a date/time?

Comment: Guys anything close to a solution could help tbh. I've been racking my brains to fix this thing and FAILING XD.

Comment: @Mark:  Fair enough, but easily interpreted — I would assume that's the moment they're interested in knowing about.

Comment: Dan: If you know what the timezone offset was on "2021-08-13 19:00", seems like it would be a matter of finding what it would be if the offset was `-4` (assuming the same location).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [timezone object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone) from the UTC offset hours via a timedelta object. Then use [tzlocal](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal) to obtain the local time zone (i.e. the one your machine is configured to use) and convert using [astimezone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone).

Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from tzlocal import get_localzone # pip install tzlocal

def to_local(s, offsethours):
    """
    convert date/time string plus UTC offset hours to date/time in
    local time zone.
    """
    dt = datetime.fromisoformat(s).replace(tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=offsethours)))
    # for Python < 3.7, use datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") instead of datetime.fromisoformat(s)
    return dt.astimezone(get_localzone())
    
    
time_string = "2021-08-13 19:00"
time_offset = -4

dt_local = to_local(time_string, time_offset)

print(repr(dt_local))
print(dt_local.isoformat())
print(dt_local.utcoffset())
# datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 14, 1, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
# 2021-08-14T01:00:00+02:00
# 2:00:00
```